# Show image label in OpenShift via oc

Tags: image, label, openshift

I have deployed a container image in OpenShift. When I in the console select Builds, clicks an image name and then an image tag I can see the labels on the image.

I would like to get this information on the command line via the oc command. However, I cannot find a way to get this specific information. Via `oc describe pod` I can find the digest of the image and if I have it my local Docker I can use `docker inspect` to see the labels. But I need the info for an image that I may not have locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this information by using :

```
 oc describe is/<image-name> -n <namespace> | grep Labels
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Console information:**

[image]

In order to get `Docker Labels` run the following command:

```
oc describe istag/<image-stream>:<tag-name> -n <namespace>
```

More information about Managing imagestreams can be found [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/openshift_images/image-streams-manage.html).